# Search bar in UICollection View is not searching result

Tags: swift, uicollectionview, uisearchbar

I am trying to make the Search bar  that can filter the search result for `UICollectionView`. I made a custom `UICollectionViewCell` class

```
class toolCollectionViewCell: UICollectionViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var imageViewCell: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var toolTitle: UILabel!

}
```

Both of these `IBoutlets` are link the corresponding elements in the storyboard .For filtering the search result into the `UICollectionView`

```
 func updateSearchResults(for searchController: UISearchController)
        {
            let searchString = searchController.searchBar.text
            filtered = items.filter({ (item) -> Bool in
                let countryText: NSString = item as NSString
                return (countryText.range(of: searchString!, options: NSString.CompareOptions.caseInsensitive).location) != NSNotFound
            })
            collectionView.reloadData()
        }
```

> The problem is that search is not working correctly. **Search result always filter to First item of collection view**. How to correct the search? you can [download](https://drive.google.com/file/d/18M2O5g5YrLlqtNVons6RsSsk6RkDpsl4/view?usp=sharing) the project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot to change the cell text in this method:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! toolCollectionViewCell

        //configureCell(cell: cell as! toolCollectionViewCell, forItemAtIndexPath: indexPath as NSIndexPath)
        cell.imageViewCell=cell.viewWithTag(1) as! UIImageView
        if searchActive {
            cell.imageViewCell.image=imageViewArray[indexPath.row]
            cell.toolTitle.text = filtered[indexPath.row]
        } else {
            cell.imageViewCell.image=imageViewArray[indexPath.row]
            cell.toolTitle.text = items[indexPath.row]
        }
        return cell      //return your cell
    }
```

And this will not work with images. You have to use dictionary with food name as a key and image as value, or better to create something like class Food with title field and image field. Then filter this class by it's title.

And I changed this method as well:

```
func updateSearchResults(for searchController: UISearchController) {
     // better way is to use "guard" or "if let searchString = searchString { ... }", 
     // because using searchString! could produce a crash in some cases.
     guard let searchString = searchController.searchBar.text else {
         return
     }

     filtered = items.filter({ (item) -> Bool in
        let countryText: NSString = item as NSString
        return countryText.lowercased.contains(searchString.lowercased())
    })

    collectionView.reloadData()        
}
```

Here is working example with class and images -  [Download](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1Jd0txadLuwRk9QZ7fAOwQMAOcKxORDGm)

Comment: Search is not working how to make the class and append it data members to array of images and array of titles.please help ?

Comment: @ajadka I attached example with class

Comment: You have provided me the same link that i have provided for download.It is same project that i have provided 
 https://drive.google.com/file/d/18M2O5g5YrLlqtNVons6RsSsk6RkDpsl4/view .

Comment: My fault, try again please